# How can i plot the variable stepsize ODE solver chooses in matlab?

Tags: matlab, ode

im trying to plot the stepsize for ODE45 and ODE15s against x but I have no clue how to find the values for each step size. any ideas?

Comment: You have the time vector, just `diff` it

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly, exactly what needed.